# Arguments to make OpenSSL run faster

Tags: openssl

Is there a way to run `openssl.exe` faster? For example you can run `gzip` with the argument `--fast`. Is there anything like that for openssl?

If not is there an encryption type that is known to be faster - not concerned if the speed means I sacrifice encryption complexity/protection. Currently I am using `aes-256-cbc` and its very slow for 100mb files (takes about 30 seconds).

Comment: Can you leverage the AES-NI cpu extentions found in newer CPU’s with `-evp` ? http://ask.xmodulo.com/check-aes-ni-enabled-openssl.html

Comment: Just have a look into the ciphers supported by your OpenSSL and run tests with all of them.